# Why are documents from Office 2007/2010 missing headers when opened in OpenOffice 3.2?

Tags: 10.04, openoffice.org

I am on a project to migrate Windows 7 to Ubuntu 10.04 but I am facing a problem. Headers and footers are missing in all documents sent from Windows 7 office 2007/2010 to Ubuntu 10.04 with OpenOffice 3.2

Can anyone help

Comment: ok almost there! Now we just need you to add which version of Office is on the windows machine to your question.

Comment: @Deepak - I would recommend you spend half-an-hour installing a test build on 11.10 that has libreoffice 3.4 - this has much better MS Office support that OpenOffice 3.2.  You can always revert back quickly to a 10.04 desktop install.

Comment: I'd recommend installing libreoffice 3.4 on top of 10.04.

Comment: OP are you still looking for an answer? If so, you may need to repost your question as this is flagged for closure. Regards,

Answer (score 1):

It is a bit TOO LATE! but there has been several important changes in LibreOffice (since OpenOffice was removed as the default a couple of versions ago) that actually touch this kind of incompatibility. Of course you will still find problems but on the Microsoft side, for example the issues regarding ODF 1.2 standards which still affect 2007 and 2010 ([See Here](https://wiki.documentfoundation.org/ReleaseNotes/3.5#ODF_1.2_Conforming_Documents))

If you happen to update a little from 10.04 to 10.10 you can try the latest LibreOffice from this PPA: https://launchpad.net/~libreoffice/+archive/ppa

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:libreoffice/ppa`

That would really help you with several issues. It did for me but with 2007. Have not tested 2010 yet.